# Create files in fuse using C

Tags: c, filesystems, mount, fuse

Im trying to have fuse create files when I mount the system using the init function. However whenever I mount my system the process never ends. Then i cant unmount it afterwards. How do i fix this.

```
void file_init(struct fuse_conn_info *conn){
FILE *fp;
fp=fopen("/data1/fuse/file.txt","w+");
fclose(fp);
}
```

Thats the code im using. I need to create multiple files but I cant even get this 1 file to work.

Comment: how about checking for errors and outputing an error message on failure.  I.E. if(NULL == fp) { perror(" fopen failed" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE); }'  that way a meaningful message will be output to stderr if the fopen fails

Answer (score 1):

Check the return of `fopen` if you want to know why it fails:

```
fp = fopen("/data1/fuse/file.txt", "w+");
if (fp == NULL) {
    perror("fopen");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
fclose(fp);
```

If `data1` is in the same directory (not in the root path), change

```
fp=fopen("/data1/fuse/file.txt","w+");
```

to

```
fp=fopen("data1/fuse/file.txt","w+"); /* remove the first backslash */
```